# Android Third Media Start Error

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

My application JAVA code is here:

```
final MediaPlayer muzik1=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.one);
    final MediaPlayer muzik2=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.two);
    final MediaPlayer muzik3=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.three);
    final MediaPlayer muzik4=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.four);
    final MediaPlayer muzik5=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.five);
    final MediaPlayer muzik6=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.six);
    final MediaPlayer muzik7=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.seven);
    final MediaPlayer muzik8=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.eight);
    final MediaPlayer muzik9=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.nine);
    final Button bir=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bir);
    final Button iki=(Button)findViewById(R.id.iki);
    final Button uc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.uc);
    final Button dort=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dort);
    final Button bes=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bes);
    final Button alti=(Button)findViewById(R.id.alti);
    final Button yedi=(Button)findViewById(R.id.yedi);
    final Button sekiz=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sekiz);
    final Button dokuz=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dokuz);
    bir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            muzik1.start();
        }
    });
    iki.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            muzik2.start();
        }
    });
    uc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            muzik3.start();

        }

    });
    dort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            muzik4.start();
        }
    });
    bes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            muzik5.start();
        }
    });
    alti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            muzik6.start();
        }
    });
    yedi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            muzik7.start();
        }
    });
    sekiz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            muzik8.start();
        }
    });
    dokuz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            muzik9.start();
        }
    });
```

And my problem: Button "bir" and "iki" click start media is work. But, "uc", "dort", etc. button click start media is not working. (Application error and shuts down.) How can I solve?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Unfortunately, [Application name] stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Try using one `MediaPlayer mp` object for all the music files instead of a different one for each file, if you don't need them to **overlap** each other. 
This way the same `mp` object will be created for each time a button is clicked. You can use `mp.stop()` to stop the MediaPlayer from playing .
Also, check all of your resource files are in the right places in your file tree, and all are accessible. 
[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) are the docs for MediaPlayer from Android  Developers site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AudioTrack. You can get some information from here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html